# Simple way to un-scale target & prediction after it has been removed from its original dataset

Tags: arrays, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

I have normalized my data using the following:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
train = scaler.fit_transform(train)
test = scaler.transform(test)
```

I later split my train and test sets into my X and y's:

```
X_train, y_train = train[:,1:21], train[:, np.shape(train)[1] - 2:]
X_test, y_test = test[:,1:21], test[:, np.shape(test)[1] - 2:]
```

I then pass these into a complex ML code.

I want to be able to easily revert my `y_test` and my `y_pred` that gets spit out by this code into their un-normalized scale (for plotting purposes).

I know that `y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)` could be used if `transform()` had been applied to `y_test` rather than `train`.

Is there a solution to this that I am overlooking?

Comment: The way I see it, you are better having two separate scalers, on for features, one for target. Otherwise, you can either concatenate `X_test, y_pred` and use that transform or rescale by manually by accessing `scaler.scale_` and `scaler.mean_`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, thank you for your comment. I will apply two separate scalers. That may be just the simplest answer to this.